# how to solve multiple js file conflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used multiple js file, but if i use that both are not working,so how to solve that issue.

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>  
 <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script> 
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("table") 
.tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
 });
```

Comment: It will be jquery version conflict. Use single latest jquery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add your highest preferred js like jquery. and the its low precedence

Like in your example.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: good. but i got this error from script.js:Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tablesorter'

Comment: But you have asked regarding the question for JS conflict issue. Please be clear with question.

Comment: my issue is tablesort is not working, help me.how to solve that issue

Comment: if i use this:  $.noConflict();
     jQuery("table").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: jQuery("#pager")});  i got this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined line __jquery.tablesorter.js:862

Comment: Just rearrange you js files as I describe above, If still ot working then rearrange your tablesorter js last three position but dont move first three.

Comment: i rearranged bit i got this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined line __jquery.tablesorter.js:862

Comment: Did you put js at last position.? If yes and still it occurs then may be it requires some more dependencies.

Comment: can you try by removing "__" before jquery.tablesorter.js, you can find here http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

if you use the plugins based on `jQuery`, so you should make `a clear understand` what the jQuery version that plugin need, and you just use only one version of `jQuery`, and include the jQuery's file `firstly`, then include other js file.